# How to convert a textual image (computer typed) into string in java

Tags: java, image, algorithm

I am new to this site.

Can anyone give me some idea on how I can convert an image (eg. a screenshot) which has only computer typed text in it to a String.

I am not talking about identifying hand-written text here which will require AI and all. It is a standard font. I think it should be possible.

Just share me the necessary resources I would need, I will try to figure the rest out myself.

Thanks.

Comment: This is referred to as Optical Character Recognition (OCR).  Google that.  The program Tesseract https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract is an open source OCR engine.

Comment: You need some [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) package, like [Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974645/using-tesseract-from-java), [Asprise Java OCR](https://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html) or [JavaOCR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/).

Comment: @jdehesa If I download JavaOCR, can I use the methods like I normally do by importing it into my code, or is there a different way of using these external libraries.

Comment: Please note that asking for third-party resources is off-topic on StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and check what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Learner'sPoint I don't really have experience with these packages, but yes, in principle the links I posted are for libraries that you can use from Java code to integrate into your application. You can also search for standalone OCR applications if you want, there are all sorts of options really.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for your quick response. I got what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have converted it into an image, it normally requires some OCR algorithms because font type and sizes may change, the anti-alias might blur the image further, and the background may be different.

Let's say you fixed all those conditions, you can convert the image into a grayscale matrix, and then just search the occurrence of a matching conditions.